# Optional URL parameter on Pyramid route

Tags: python, url-routing, pyramid

For example I want to use the same route to submit a form and to show the content of forms based on their id number.

I thought a rematched parameter:

```
config.add_route('poll', '/poll/{id}*')
```

was enough but it doesn't work. When the method POST finishes I want it to load the page showing the result but it throws a 404 error.

Comment: I think the asterisk should go inside the brackets.

Answer (score 6):

From http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#route-pattern-syntax:

```
config.add_route('poll', '/poll/{id:.*}')
```

Note that when generating a url via `request.route_url('poll', id='5')` the `id` parameter is required, you cannot leave it out. You can solve this with a pregenerator:

```
def pregen(request, elements, kw):
    kw.setdefault('id', '')
    return elements, kw
config.add_route('poll', '/poll/{id:.*}', pregenerator=pregen)
```

This will allow you to use `request.route_url('poll')` as well as `request.route_url('poll', id='5')`.